# Query date less than today in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb data such as below:

```
{
   "program" : "DATE TRAINING",
   "durationStart" : "2014-12-20",
   "durationEnd" : "2014-12-20",
   "status" : "Approved"
}
```

I'd like to count how many data is `durationEnd` date is less than today date. From the data above I know I have one.

Using nodejs I have tried with the below code but no luck so far. My `console.log` output for count is 0.

```
var today = new Date();
collection.count({
            $or: [{
                status: "Pending " + config.TD
            }, {
                status: "Approved",                                  
                durationEnd : {$lte : today }
            }],
             evaluationFlag: null
        }, function(err, count) {
        console.log("count is " + count);
      }
   });
```

Comment: Your example document, does not have a username field, hence it is evaluated to `null` during the query, which most likely does not match `req.user.username`, hence the number of returned documents is 0.

Comment: sorry i have removed req.user.username...even the updated one the returned document is still 0...

Comment: Ok, after the edit which removed the username: your dates in the documents are Strings, which don't match a date. Change them to ISODates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates are string not real Date:

use this:

```
var date = new Date();
var today = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();

collection.count({
        $or: [{
            status: "Pending " + config.TD
        }, {
            status: "Approved",
            durationEnd : {$lte : today }
        }],
         evaluationFlag: null
    }, function(err, count) {
    console.log("count is " + count);
  }
});
```

Comment: However, I'd strongly suggest saving dates as ISODates instead of strings, since internally the comparison will be an integer comparison (msecs since epoch) rather than a string comparison, which is more costly and therefor slower.